# How to add function that listen for changes in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, listener, product

I have a list of products, after clicking on a product, product-details opens, in which there are details of this product. The URL path is the id of the product, that is getting and then searching for that product in the database. But to view the data for this product I have to click on the button. How to do it automatically and then listen for changes?

product-details.component.ts:

```
export class ProductDetalisComponent implements OnInit {
  private ngUnsubscribe = new Subject();

  product = [];
  product_id;

  constructor(private productService: ProductService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }


  ngOnInit() {

    this.route.paramMap.pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
      .subscribe(params => 
      {
          this.product_id = [params.get('productId')];
          this.getProductById();
      });
  }

  getProductById() {
    this.productService.getProductById(this.product_id)
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          this.product = res;
        },
        err => console.log(err)
      );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
    this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
  }

}
```

product-details.component.html:

```
  <button type="button" (click)="getProductById();">Product</button>

  <p>Name: <a> {{product.name}} </a></p>
  <p>Price: <a> {{product.price}} </a></p>
  <p>Id: <a> {{product._id}} </a></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?:

```
export class ProductDetalisComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private productService: ProductService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  product = [];
  product_id;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.product_id = params.get('productId');
      this.getProductById(); // <=====
    });
  }

  getProductById() {
    this.productService.getProductById(this.product_id).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.product = res;
      },
      err => console.log(err)
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean :D Wow I thought that I should use an observable or something like this, but it's so simple and it works. Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: You are already using observable and I see that you don't unsubscribe, that can cause memory leaks. I suggest you to look at this article: https://netbasal.com/when-to-unsubscribe-in-angular-d61c6b21bad3

Comment: Thank you :) On your advice I just added there unsubscribe function, but I'm not sure if it works well, could you please check if I did it correctly? I'll post it as the next answer

Comment: Do not post it as an answer. Just edit your question.

Comment: I edited as well, please read the article I send to you, or read more about subscriptions and observables. Once you understand, the whole world will become just simpler.

Comment: Okay, I read your article completely. Unfortunately, I am only beginner and a lot ahead of me. But thank you so much :) I didn't notice that I put this method in the wrong place.